# how to search value in json array mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, search

I saved some array value via JSON encode to some table recode.here is JSON value
`category_id ---- ["2","3"]`

and I need search query to search category_id.someone can explain to me how I do this

`$search=$_GET['sq'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE category_id =".$search;`

Comment: Use the `JSON_SEARCH()` function.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here how I got the correct query using JSON_SEARCH method

`SELECT * FROM`table`WHERE JSON_SEARCH(category_id, 'all', '%1%') IS NOT NULL`